# Nginx Regex URL Rewrite Not Working

Tags: regex, nginx

Why on earth does this not work when all my other URL rewrites work perfectly:

```
rewrite "^/search/?\?q(.+)$" /search.php?q$1 break;
```

I did restart nginx and all of that.

Comment: how do your urls look line? what's the expected result?

Comment: I'm trying to change `search?q=whatever` OR `search/?q=whatever` to `search.php?q=whatever`

Comment: this should work. what's you error? also, try with `\1` instead of `$1` as a replacement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite only works on uri path. You don't need to rewrite the query string part because by default it's automatically attached to the new url.

```
rewrite /search /search.php break;
```

For example, /search?q=something will be written to /search.php?q=something.

See http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite for more detail. This line below addresses your question

> Also rewrite operates only on path, not parameters.